# how to implement custom cloud worker

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2, cloud, message-queue

I am designing a cloud app and need a worker process which scours my database looking for work, and then performs it.

Most of the info I seem to find on the subject of background tasks in the cloud involves some kind of scheduler and/or queuing system.

What I have doesn't quite fit into the "run this task every 5 minutes" or "add this to the queue to be executed later" models. I think the main difference to my problem is that the workers themselves find work to do, rather than being assigned it by a periodic scheduler or an external process that generates work.

What I have is basically a giant table where each entry has three fields:

1. `job`: a small task to be performed, lets say it gets the last message from a twitter account and stores it in the database
2. the `interval` at which to perform that job: say every 5 minutes, N.B. the interval is arbitrary and different for each entry in the table
3. the last `date` when the job was performed

The way I would implement this is to have a worker which has an infinite loop. When it enters the loop, it scours the database a)looking for items whose `date + interval < currentTime`, b)when it finds one, it sets `date = currentTime`, and c)then executes the job. If there is no work ATM, it sleep for a few seconds, then tries again.

I will have many parallel workers scouring the database simultaneously, which is why I do b) first and then c) in the paragraph above. Since there are parallel workers, action a) and b) are atomic operations on the database to prevent work being duplicated. If the worker crashes after a) and b), but before it manages to finish the work, it's no big deal, and the workers can just do it at the next interval; reason for this is that the work is not performed in a time-invariant system so a backlog scenario of failed jobs has no benefit as the tasks have to be performed at their exact intervals, so it's better to skip 1 interval than to have uneven intervals between which the tasks were executed.

My question is whether that is a reasonable implementation strategy? If so, how do I bring this process to life on the cloud (I am using Heroku, but may switch to EC2 in the future)? I still haven't written any code so I would welcome other suggestions (maybe I misunderstood the use cases/applications for queue systems).

Comment: I'm not clear on why you don't want to push over a queue - this sounds near-identical to that, but rather than have workers listen, you want them to pull. Why pull instead of push?

Comment: Because I have a database of what is essentially a bunch of crontabs. Many different items which need to be executed at different recurring intervals. Any suggestions for this kind of architecture?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds so close to using something like a scheduled job that you might as well tread the well beaten path and do it the more conventional way.  There's no reason why you can't schedule a job to run once every few seconds.

However, this idea of looking for work sounds dodgy.  What happens if two workers find the same task to run at the same time for instance?  Also, are there not triggers in the application which can indicate that work needs doing?  It seems strange that you have code 'looking for work'.

You can go a very long way with simple periodic background tasks, so I would exhaust all possibilities in that area before rolling your own.